# How to configure logging for different modules from single file in python

Tags: python, logging

Suppose I have different python modules, packages and classes.

I wan't to be able to set the logging level in all of them. So I know that I can use yaml or json file to do that. But I can't figure out how to appropriately set logger name to **name** of the module. So for example I could do something like that

```
class Foo(object):

def __init__(self):
self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
self.logging.config.dictConfig(...)
...
```

But that would require the first line of code to be in every module or file. And I don't wan't to do that.

Maybe there is a better way?